# Use Image Element as background-image

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I need to preload my all image files before I run my react app. In the case I need to use it as img tag i spimpy do

`elementRef.current.appendChild(imageElement)`

but sometimes I wish to use it as background-image CSS property and there is a problem.

I tried do something like that:

```
elementRef.current.style.backgroundImage = `url(${imageElement.src})
```

that's working but just download file once again and I need to aviod that.
Hopefully you have idea how to solve my problem.

Comment: It may not be correctly resolving  ``url(${imageElement.src})``   try with ``url('${imageElement.src}')``

Comment: no, it's work fine. But that is not problem of that case. I just don't want to pass url string straight coz that call request again and download png once again. I preload everything before I runned app and keep in in HTMLImageElement. And now I want to use thatt element to somehow show it as backgdound-image or any other way just to not download png file once again.